# how to clear datatable before ajax load from another ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, codeigniter

need help i have 3 ajax where 
 - data from ajax A have button if click will show ajax B
 - data from ajax B have button if click will show ajax C
problem is when datatable from ajax A if i looking a new search
data from ajax B still the OLD how to clear data from ajax B dan C before ajax A load 
this my code for ajax A :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var save_method; //for save method string
var table; //for ajax A
var table2; // for ajax B
var table3;  // for ajax C
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>';
   // table2 = $('#table_id2').clear();
  //  table2 = $('#table_id2').rows.add(response.data);
  //  table2 = $('#table_id2').draw();
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //datatables
    table = $('#table_id').DataTable({         
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
        "deferLoading": 0,
        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "language": {
            "processing": "<span><img src='images/Preloader_3.gif'/></span>"
            }, // you can put text or html here in the language.processing setting.            
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url('infoemployee/ajax_list')?>",            
            "type": "POST",
        },      
        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },                  
        ],
    }); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this block

```
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo base_url('infoemployee/ajax_list')?>",            
        "type": "POST",
    },
```

add this above line

```
"destroy" : true,
```

Comment: hi ivan, whats mean "destroy" : true, ajax A or ajax B?

Comment: for both, you must try it for understanding

Comment: thanks ivan its works add that code to all of my ajax

Comment: hi ivan can i ask u again how to display my datatable empty before i using search ill try using '"deferLoading": 0,' but after i search new data the datatables back to show all data .. thanks before

Comment: @WahyuArtadianto when you search do you use a button or another method ?

Comment: hi ivan ill try using vote but  "need with less than 15 reputation are recorded," 

i use datatable search

Comment: Look at here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8808/solved-starting-with-empty-table

Comment: my ajax looping for searching im using "fnServerData": function( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback ) {
if(search==true) {
aoData.push({"name":"sSearch_0", "value":$('#test_ci').val() });
$.ajax( { "url": sUrl, "type": "GET", "data": aoData, "success": fnCallback, "dataType": "json", "cache": true, "async": true } );
}
search=false;
}